# sql Stored Procedures Quotes()

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, quotes

I need to generate a string like this in stored procedure.

```
select case when Sex like '%' then 'Person' end as Sex from tableName;
```

In stored Procedure I have generated like this.

```
select case when Sex like quote(%) then quote(Person) end as Sex from tableName;
```

The error i got is

```
    Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%) then quote(Person) end as Sex from tableName' at line 1   0.000 sec
```

My MariaDB version is '10.3.16-MariaDB'

Please help in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't quote the literals in the second query. Try:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN sex LIKE quote('%') THEN
           quote('Person')
       END AS sex
       FROM tablename;
```

But it doesn't make too much sense to `quote()` literals as you already have to escape any special characters in them. So applying `quote()` is superfluous.

Comment: I got every value as Null with this query not as person. But to get quotes only i used "quote" function in stored procedure and again do we need to pass values in quotations to "quote" function??

Comment: What value does `sex` have for the rows you get `NULL` for the expression. Probably `NULL`?

Comment: And yes, literals string need to be quoted no matter to which function you pass them. The parser needs to recognize them.

Comment: I have male and female values in sex column not null

Comment: Well `quote('%')` yields `'%'` -- the single quotes are in the string value itself. And these quotes are missing in `male` or `female`. I still don't get what you try to achieve with either the `quote()` call or the `CASE` expression. It seems like you just need `SELECT 'Person' sex FROM ...` if it should be person, no matter what. But well, I think the syntax issue this question was about is solved. For anything else you should ask a new question and severely elaborate on what you have and try to achieve.